# CrossOrigin cannot be resolved to a type ? Spring

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

I'm trying to enable corsOrgin in header to be able to consume rest api from my laravel app with ajax.

But after I wrote

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
```

in the client controller, it shows a warning

> CrossOrigin cannot be resolved to a type

Does somebody know how to solve this problem?

```
[@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080") problem][1]
```

Client.Controller

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/clients", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllClients() {

        List<Client> clients = clientService.loadAll();

        return new ResponseEntity<>(clients, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>rs.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>app_daoproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>app_daoproject</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
             <version>0.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>tagsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Try to check whether spring-web is on your classpath. Execute mvn dependency:tree inside of your module that contains your controller and see if its available.

Answer (score 0):

just set response header  like `res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` at server side.

```
//@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
@RequestMapping(value="getDeatils", method=RequestMethod.GET,   produces="application/json" )
public ResponseEntity<JSONObject> getTinDetails(HttpServletRequest req, @RequestParam("gstin") String gstin, HttpServletResponse res) { 

 res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

           return new ResponseEntity<JSONObject>(responceObj, HttpStatus.OK);
        }else{

                throw new UserException("_GSTC_INVALID_GSTIN_");


        }

}
```

just try this , it helps it works for me. if it helps promote

Comment: Thanks for answer but i'm getting this error https://imgur.com/a/p7Tvo3g

Comment: You need to mention 'HttpServletResponse res' in your method Parameter Section. like `public ResponseEntity<?> getClients(HttpServletResponse res){--------}`